# How to generate a QR Code with multiple values like name, email, etc in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg

I am able to create QR Code with single value by using `react-native-qrcode-svg` package. But not able to add multiple values like name,email, etc.

I have tried these :

Packages:

npm install react-native-svg --save 
react-native link react-native-svg 
npm install react-native-qrcode-svg --save

Code for generating QR Code using single value.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <QRCode
      value="Here I want to add name, email,etc"
    />
  );
 };
}
```

I want to generate something like this

[image: I want to generate something like this]

Comment: What's your needs? QRcode is like a `string` in another style, why do you want to add many things in one QRcode? If you really need it, I may recommend to input like an object or JSON style string, that let you more easily to analysis it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rn-qr-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator) module to create QRCode Image with a given string.
To generate a QRCode image with an object just do something like this

```
import RNQRGenerator from 'rn-qr-generator';
 
RNQRGenerator.generate({
  value: JSON.stringify({ email: 'some.email.com', name: 'Name' })
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  base64: false,            // default 'false'
  backgroundColor: 'black', // default 'white'
  color: 'white',           // default 'black'
})
  .then(response => {
    const { uri, width, height, base64 } = response;
    this.setState({ imageUri: uri });
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('Cannot create QR code', error));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg, the value can be an array:

`String Value of the QR code. Can also accept an array of segments as defined in Manual mode. Ex. [{ data: 'ABCDEFG', mode: 'alphanumeric' }, { data: '0123456', mode: 'numeric' }, { data: [253,254,255], mode: 'byte' }]`

Hence the code should be

```
import * as React from 'react';
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <QRCode
      value="[{ name: 'my name'},{ email: 'email@email.com' }]"
    />
  );
 };
}
```

Comment: This will give as a string but I want to generate something that is similar to the QR Code show in the question.

Comment: I have changed the code. Check once. Also, read the documentation thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

I never used react, but shouldn't be something like

```
value={`"name={name},email={email},phone={phone}"`}
```

enough to compute the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<QRCode
      value={`${email},${mdp}`}
 />
```

if you want to read the data:

```
data=result.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the QR Generator is only taking one value, but you want an object or multiple values then just pass in one value with:

```
value = JSON.stringify({qrobject)}
```

And then just do the opposite and destructure later if possible with:

```
value = JSON.parse({qrobject)}
```

before it feeds into the final function.